# i am trying to delete my record from the database that does not exist. and update my record who exist. using laravel

Tags: laravel

I am trying to delete my record from the database that does not exist. and update my record who exist. and I want to add new data in the database which is not available in database Does anyone have an idea please help me thanks.

$issue= Issue::where('project_id', $project->id)->get();

```
$isseuss= $issue->WhereNotIn('issue',$request->issue);
       $isseuss->delete();

        foreach($isseuss  as  $key =>$value){
        
            $value->date         =  $request->date[$key];
            $value->issue        =  $request->issue[$key];
            $value->project_id   =  $project->id;
            $value->save();
         }

   
    foreach($request->date  as  $key2 =>$val){
            $issue               =  new Issue;
            $issue->date         =  $val;
            $issue->issue        =  $request->issue[$key2];
            $issue->project_id   =  $project->id;
            $issue->save();
   

    }
           

   return redirect()->route('project');
```

**return $request**

```
                 {
  "_token": "r3CTg9PnUyWo8inwpmWdncV1NcQp18FCyvMI7l3B",
  "date": [
    "2020-07-26",
    "2020-07-21"
  ],
  "issue": [
    "joylink on web",
    "edit issue"
  ]
}
```

**html view**

```
                    <div class="row addmore_issues">
                      <div class="col-md-12">
                        @if(count($issues))
                        @foreach($issues   as  $key => $details)
                      
                        <div class="row">
                          <div class="col-md-5">
                            <div class="form-group">
                              <input required type="date" value="{{$details->date}}" 
                      name="date[]" class="form-control"
                                     aria-describedby="emailHelp" >
                            </div>
                          </div>
                          <div class="col-md-5">
                            <div class="form-group">
                              <input required type="text"  value="{{$details->issue}}"  
                  name="issue[]" class="form-control"
                                     aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Issue...">
                            </div>
                          </div>
                          <div class="col-md-1 mt12">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger waves-effect waves- 
                          light btn-sm delete">
                              <i
                                 class="fa fa-times">
                              </i>
                            </button>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        @endforeach
                        @else
                           <div class="row">
                          <div class="col-md-5">
                            <div class="form-group">
                              <input required type="date" value="" name="date[]" class="form-control"
                                     aria-describedby="emailHelp" >
                            </div>
                          </div>
                          <div class="col-md-5">
                            <div class="form-group">
                              <input required type="text"  value=""  name="issue[]" class="form-control"
                                     aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Issue...">
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        @endif

                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <!--end row-->
```

Comment: Can you be more clear to what exactly is your problem and what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to update my record that exists in the database and I want to delete my record that does not exist in the database and want to add my new record  please see image https://ibb.co/R61QYZp

Comment: Still not very clear. Are you getting any error right now?

Comment: please just only tell me how can I update multiple records related to project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To delete the resources not availabe on the request:

```
$isseuss = Issue::WhereNotIn('issue', $request->issue)->delete(); //$request->issue has to be array
```

I am not able to visualize what are those `date` and `issue` data are related with each other also where and what project id represents for this transaction but, you can use `updateOrCreate()` eloquent method for creating a resource if not exist on Database or update the available resource Eg:

```
    Issue::updateOrCreate([
        'issue'      => 'issue',
        'project_id' => 'project_id'
    ],
        [
            'date' => 'data'
        ]);
```

Here it checks if a row where column `issue` with value 'issue' and column `project_id` with value 'project_id' exists or not. If exists it updates `date` column of those row otherwise create a new row with provided value.

Answer (score 0):

u cant count the issue variable if its value is greater then 0 then u can delete it or if not then u can insert it in db

````
if(count($issue)>0){
$issue->delete();

}else{
//type your insert code here
}```
````